# Conversion from float to char[32] (or vice-versa) in C

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point, char, hex

I have two variables: a `float` named `diff` with a value like `894077435904.000000` (not always only with zero in the decimal part) and a `char[32]` which is the result of a double-sha256 calculation. I need to do a comparison between them (`if(hash < diff) { //do someting }` ), but for this I need to convert one to the type of the other.

Is there a way to accomplish this? For example, converting the `float` to a `char*` (and using `strcmp` to do the comparison) or the `char*` to `float` (and using the above approach - if it's even possible, considering the `char*` is 256 bits, or 32 bytes long)?

I have tried converting `float` to `char*` like this:

```
char hex_str[2*sizeof(diff)+1];
snprintf(hex_str, sizeof(hex_str), "%0*lx", (int)(2*sizeof diff), (long unsigned int)diff);
printf("%s\n", hex_str);
```

When I have `diff=894077435904.000000` I get `hex_str=d02b2b00`. How can I verify if this value is correct? Using [this converter](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) I obtain different results.

Comment: You need to do the math to convert the difficulty to a target and then you need to compare the target to the hash result (probably with `memcmp`). See [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty) for more on how to convert difficulty to a target.

Comment: I already do this math (I read the `bits` from json-rpc interface, convert to `unsigned int` and pass to the function listed in the link you post). Now I just need compare the difficulty with the hash, I guess.

Comment: Okay. Use `memcmp` for that. If the hash is less than the target, you win.

Comment: Oh, you probably will need to convert it from hex to raw first. Really, you shouldn't have it in hex in the first place. Hex is really only for human consumption.

Comment: Also you can do it by using `>>` shift operator

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I search for `memcmp` on the internet. Is it possible use if the 2 values have different sizes? (float is 4 byte `long`, and the `char*` 32 bytes long, in the example I saw both values are 6 bytes long)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz What you mean convert to raw? You mean the `char*`? I think already is (I do not change anything about it after the hash calculation).

Comment: @EsmaeelE Can you expand this idea? I am not very confortable working with bitwise operators.

Comment: @KleberMota Okay, so it's the raw value? Not hex? In that case, you can just use `memcmp` to compare the two raw values.

Comment: @KleberMota I try to prepare a working example to give you a clue. also you must know difference of Big-endian and little-endian difference.

Comment: _I got differents results_ See [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) : `894077435904` = `0xd02b2b00 * 256` = `0xd02b2b0000`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz again, how I could use `memcmp` with values of different sizes (`float` = 4 bytes long and `char[32]` = 32 bytes long)? just compare 4bytes of each (`memcmp(diff, hash, 4)`)? How this will give me a meaning result?

Comment: @EsmaeelE I understand the difference between BigEndian and LittleEndian. I think both values already have the same orientation, no? Is this really relevant here?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz *meaningful

Comment: @KleberMota I thought you converted the difficulty to a target already? The target should be the same size as the hash. And they should both be in big endian form.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that's exactly my question: how take a `float` value (difficulty) and converto to a `char[32]` array (target). The method I used so far (see the code in the question) do not give a 32 bytes `char` array, and the hex value converted again to decimal do not match with my original difficulty value.

Comment: @Kleber Mota i am understand  applying shift operator on float variable not possible in C and for that we need to implement a new method that complicates your solution.  i dont want to express any method that add complexity to it. give me time to find or implement feasible solution.

Comment: @KleberMota yes in your case both float and char array are in same endian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is explained in great detail [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty).

1. Create an array of 32 unsigned bytes, set all its values to zero.
2. Extract the top byte from the difficulty and subtract that from 32.
3. Copy the bottom three bytes from the difficulty into the array, starting the number of bytes into the array that you computed in step 2.
4. This array now contains the difficulty in raw binary. Use `memcmp` to compare it to the hash in raw binary.

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* tohex="0123456789ABCDEF";

void computeDifficulty(unsigned char* buf, unsigned j)
{
    memset(buf, 0, 32);
    int offset = 32 - (j >> 24);
    buf[offset] = (j >> 16) & 0xffu;
    buf[offset + 1] = (j >> 8) & 0xffu;
    buf[offset + 2] = j & 0xffu;
}

void showDifficulty(unsigned j)
{
    unsigned char buf[32];
    computeDifficulty(buf, j);
    printf("%x -> ", j);
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
        printf("%c%c ", tohex[buf[i] >> 4], tohex[buf[i] & 0xf]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    showDifficulty(0x1b0404cbu);
}
```

Output:

```
1b0404cb -> 00 00 00 00 00 04 04 CB 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```